# how to get public timeline in twitterizer for WPF

Tags: wpf, twitterizer

I can get users tweets in my WPF application. I tried publictimeline with all overloaded methods but all are giving same problem System.NullReferenceException but when i try to get public tweets(public timeline); it fails. Below is my code.
    using Twitterizer;

```
            TwitterResponse<TwitterStatusCollection> myTweets;
            TwitterResponse<TwitterStatusCollection> publicTweets;
            myTweets = TwitterTimeline.HomeTimeline(tokens);

            foreach (var item in myTweets.ResponseObject)
            {
                String textStatus = item.Text;
                myTweetsTB.AppendText(textStatus + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            publicTweets = TwitterTimeline.PublicTimeline();
            foreach (var item in publicTweets.ResponseObject)
            {
                if (item != null)
                {
                    string textStatus = item.Text;
                    publicTweetsTB.AppendText(textStatus + Environment.NewLine);
                }
                else return;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

`PublicTimeline()` is deprecated.
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/public_timeline

You do realise that this would returns 20 random public tweets? If that is what you want, you can use the new GET, 'statuses/sample':
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/sample